# Creating histogram plot

Tags: python, graph, histogram, bar-chart

I have a 2D array. Lets say column 1 (a distribution), ranges from 0-2, column 2, ranges from 2-4, column 3, from 4-6 etc. I want to have a histogram plot for each of the columns, colored by the range, so for

```
column 1, blue-0 and red-2, 
column 2, blue-2 and red-4,
```

...and so on.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I understand what you want, but you should check out [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/), in particular [matplotlib.pyplot.hist](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist).

Comment: You could use the code in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37559471/2087463) or this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37548733/2087463) as an example for plotting histograms.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at [`matplotlib.pyplot.hist`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but I think you could have a look at [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/).