# How to make matplotlib/pandas bar chart look like hist chart?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib, plot

## Plotting Differences between `bar` and `hist`

Given some data in a [`pandas.Series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html#pandas-series) , `rv`, there is a difference between

1. Calling [`hist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.hist.html) directly on the data to plot
2. Calculating the histogram results (with [`numpy.histogram`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html#numpy-histogram)) then plotting with [`bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html)

### Example Data Generation

```
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12.0, 8.0)
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

# Setup size and distribution
size = 50000
distribution = stats.norm()

# Create random data
rv = pd.Series(distribution.rvs(size=size))
# Get sane start and end points of distribution
start = distribution.ppf(0.01)
end = distribution.ppf(0.99)

# Build PDF and turn into pandas Series
x = np.linspace(start, end, size)
y = distribution.pdf(x)
pdf = pd.Series(y, x)

# Get histogram of random data
y, x = np.histogram(rv, bins=50, normed=True)
# Correct bin edge placement
x = [(a+x[i+1])/2.0 for i,a in enumerate(x[0:-1])]
hist = pd.Series(y, x)
```

### `hist()` Plotting

```
ax = pdf.plot(lw=2, label='PDF', legend=True)
rv.plot(kind='hist', bins=50, normed=True, alpha=0.5, label='Random Samples', legend=True, ax=ax)
```

[image: hist plotting]

### `bar()` Plotting

```
ax = pdf.plot(lw=2, label='PDF', legend=True)
hist.plot(kind='bar', alpha=0.5, label='Random Samples', legend=True, ax=ax)
```

[image: bar plotting]

### How can the `bar` plot be made to look like the `hist` plot?

The use case for this is needing to save only the *histogrammed* data to use and plot later (it is typically smaller in size than the original data).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Bar plotting differences

Obtaining a `bar` plot that looks like the `hist` plot requires some manipulating of default behavior for `bar`.

1. Force `bar` to use actual x data for plotting range by passing both x (`hist.index`) and y (`hist.values`). [The default `bar` behavior is to plot the y data against an arbitrary range and put the x data as the label](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13521621/2087463).
2. Set the `width` parameter to be related to actual step size of x data (The default is `0.8`)
3. Set the `align` parameter to `'center'`.
4. Manually set the axis legend.

These changes need to be made via [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/index.html)'s [`bar()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar) called on the axis (`ax`) instead of [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org)'s [`bar()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#bar-plots) called on the data (`hist`).

### Example Plotting

```
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12.0, 8.0)
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

# Setup size and distribution
size = 50000
distribution = stats.norm()

# Create random data
rv = pd.Series(distribution.rvs(size=size))
# Get sane start and end points of distribution
start = distribution.ppf(0.01)
end = distribution.ppf(0.99)

# Build PDF and turn into pandas Series
x = np.linspace(start, end, size)
y = distribution.pdf(x)
pdf = pd.Series(y, x)

# Get histogram of random data
y, x = np.histogram(rv, bins=50, normed=True)
# Correct bin edge placement
x = [(a+x[i+1])/2.0 for i,a in enumerate(x[0:-1])]
hist = pd.Series(y, x)

# Plot previously histogrammed data
ax = pdf.plot(lw=2, label='PDF', legend=True)
w = abs(hist.index[1]) - abs(hist.index[0])
ax.bar(hist.index, hist.values, width=w, alpha=0.5, align='center')
ax.legend(['PDF', 'Random Samples'])
```

---

[image: histogrammed plot]

Comment: I got this error: `line 7, in <module>
    matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'style' ` 

I am on `Python 2.7.12`.

Comment: You may have a different version of matplotlib.  Google for this error, there should be lots of existing SO answers relating to matplotlib configuration and parameter settings across the different versions.

Answer (score 2):

Another, simpler solution is to create fake samples that reproduce the same histogram and then simply use hist().

I.e., after retrieving `bins` and `counts` from stored data, do

```python
fake = np.array([])
for i in range(len(counts)):
    a, b = bins[i], bins[i+1]
    sample = a + (b-a)*np.random.rand(counts[i])
    fake = np.append(fake, sample)

plt.hist(fake, bins=bins)
```